# How can I range over a channel of unknown types in golang

Tags: csv, go, channel

I have a function which receives a string and based on that it creates a channel of a type based on the string value. This channel is then sent off to be populated in another thread.

In this function, I then want to **range** over the populated values and use them.

However, I get an error: **"cannot range over myChan (type interface {})"**

Here is an example of my code:

```
func myFunc(input string) {
    var myChan interface{}

    switch input {
    case "one":
        myChan = make(chan One)
    case "two":
        myChan = make(chan Two)
    }

    go doStuff(&myChan)

    for _, item := range myChan {
        fmt.Println(item)
    }
}
```

Please help me understand how to accomplish this?

Edit: I'm sorry my question was not clear enough. The line go doStuff(&myChan) is actually this:

```
go gocsv.UnmarshalToChan(clientsFile, &myChan)
```

According to the documentation of gocsv UnmarshalToChan "The channel must have a concrete type." That is why I cannot have a **chan interface{}**

Comment: It won't work this way. It could work like myChan would be "chan interface{}". But even better is create not to use channel of interface{}, but channel of interfaces, that have some specific method. And please, tell us why you need something like that, because I've never need to create a channel of something, that I don't know what is it.

Comment: I receive a csv filename. Different files will have different structures inside. I then send it to go gocsv.UnmarshalToChan(clientsFile, &myChan). gocsv is  "github.com/gocarina/gocsv"  Inside the range will also not just be println, I will do some processing and write it to a db.

Comment: Can you include that processing and write-to-db code in as methods of the types?  Like `Two.Process()` and `Two.WriteDB(dbHandle)`?  If you can isolate their behavior like that, you can make the channel be of an interface with those methods on it, and the range loop can simply accept anything that fulfills it, calling those methods as they get the items from the channel.  That would also open the code up to dependency injection testing, as hard-coded concrete types can make proper unit testing difficult or impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but looking at the code you've written, this is how I would get resolve the cannot range issue. This is going to deadlock, because not everything is defined...but ranging isn't an issue or shouldn't be. Also the doStuff code, should signal when the channel should be closed, maybe passed in a wait group, keep track with a counter, etc.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

// One ...
type One struct{}

// Two ...
type Two struct{}

func doStuff(*interface{}) {}

func myFunc(input string) {
    var myChan interface{}
    switch input {
    case "one":
        myChan = make(chan One)
    case "two":
        myChan = make(chan Two)
    }
    // might have to move this line of code into the switch block below...
    // see commented example
    go doStuff(&myChan)

    switch myChan.(type) {
    case chan One:
        // in this way you're not passing an interface{} but a chan or type One or Two
        // go doStuff(&myChan.(chan One))
        for item := range myChan.(chan One) {
            fmt.Println(item)
        }
    case chan Two:
        // go doStuff(&myChan.(chan One))
        for item := range myChan.(chan Two) {
            fmt.Println(item)
        }
    default:
        log.Fatalln("Unknown type entered")
    }

}

func main() {
    myFunc("one")
}
```

Comment: This is kind of what I am doing now. I moved the doStuff which is actually gocsv.UnmarshalToChan(clientsFile, &myChan) and the **range** into the first switch statement. It is a bad solution for me because there can be 15 to 20 different csv files and I have to do almost the same thing with all of them, so it means 20 blocks of duplicate code in the switch statement. I will accept your answer - I have kind of given up on finding the _correct_ way, but I think it might involve **reflect**

Comment: Yeah this would be a pain to use with 20 cases to check for.. and each csv has completely different structures.. youd have to defined 20 different structs. If you can programmically nornalize the csvs then you wouldnt need as many structs. Or since they are csvs, they are 1 dimensional.  Use a  []map[string]string and forget the channels. Where the key in the map is equal csv header.

Answer (score 0):

**myChan** variable isn't a channel, a type channel is created in this way: **chan** interface{}

for example if you want a channel to pass any type you can use this:

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan interface{}, 1)

    go func() {
        for a := range c {
            fmt.Println(a)
        }
    }()

    c <- 21
    c <- "jazz"
    c <- person{"Chet", 88}

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}

type person struct {
    Name string
    Age int
}
```

full example: https://play.golang.org/p/BJrAHiSAaw

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear enough. I have updated it. If I make a "chan interface{}" then I cannot do "myChan = make(chan One)" in the switch statement